# HP Pavilion dv3 volume control display driver on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, display, hp-laptop

I've recently bought an HP Pavilion dv3-2150ep and I'm having a hard time getting the volume control display to work as expected. The control is a back-lit touch-sensitive bar above the keyboard. Now the buttons to turn the volume up and down actually do it, but the lightning is not changing at all. The mute button does change color when toggled.

I'm not sure if I'm missing any drivers here (I've installed all of those on the HP support page that seem to have something to do with sound and/or display) or if I have to activate this somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have an HP dv5, and the backlit bar between "+" and "-" was always lit completely from left to right. Independent of the current volume. I always thought it would be a nice feature if the bar showed the current volume level, I didn't know that it is a present feature. The notebook came with Vista, but in the meantime I have upgraded to 7.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is part of the HP Quick Launch Buttons. HP does not supply any windows 7 drivers for this model. This may change in due course, until then you can try the Vista driver (install in compatibility mode if necessary).

Also run Windows Update.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the "HP Quick Launch Buttons" were the ones. And since Windows 7 drivers weren't available, I had to go with the Windows Vista drivers, which don't work.

Comment: i'm afraid then you're in the waiting game until HP provides Windows 7 drivers. try their tech support, with luck you end up with someone competent. :)

Answer (score 0):

By "display" they are referring to video card drivers. You will want to look into the drivers under the "Keyboard, Mouse and Input Devices" section [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=2093&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=au&lang=en&product=3985016). As Molly pointed out there is no Windows 7 driver currently available for this model, but most Vista drivers should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with volume  I have realtek driver from Windows update and my mute button now changing colour although my play/pause and stuff won't work, I have quick play working when I installed Vista drivers but I don't really need it...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't a clear answer, but I had this issue on Vista.  I don't think it's the fact that the drivers are vista drivers - *there's an issue on Vista with the Vista drivers*.

I don't remember the exact fix, but I had to open the control panel audio panel and then do something in the mixer.

Try Googling "Frozen Quick Launch bar in Vista after driver update)

Update -  Some links:

- [Yahoo Answers](http://jorgelmatos.blogspot.com/2007/02/hp-dv9000-laptop-quickplay-and-vista.html)
- [Some Random Blog](http://jorgelmatos.blogspot.com/2007/02/hp-dv9000-laptop-quickplay-and-vista.html)

I haven't found my original solution that I found the first time, but many people are pointing to a windows service or program file not having permission or not auto starting. It could also be the Vista drivers though.

good luck.